# Jquery multiple forms in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following dynamically generated HTML

```
<div id="1">
<form name = "inpForm">
<input name="FirstName" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</div>

<div id="2">
<form name = "inpForm">
<input name="FirstName" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

The outer divs have different IDs but the form names are the same. I am using Jquery to perform some validation when the form is submitted. However, when the second form is submitted, I always get the values of the first form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form[name="inpForm"]').live('submit', function () {
        alert($('input[name="FirstName"]').val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

How can I modify myJquery to find the "FirstName" element that matches the current form where the submit was triggered? 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add some context:

```
alert($(this).find('input[name="FirstName"]').val());
```

Comment: @MikeRobinson - It worked. I cannot accept an answer until 10 minutes have passed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` (the form-element) as context-argument:

```
alert($('input[name="FirstName"]',this).val());
```